SFTP with private key as a buffer in curl
How to connect to remote server by just providing private key as a string/ buffer in SFTP  and libcurl client in C++.
I want to connect to remote server using SFTP and libcurl by only providing private key as a buffer. I have already implemented a successful file transfer client in C++ by providing key file path. But I need to pass private key as a string because of the security reasons. Making a temporary file is also not a solution.
My question is, is this possible with libcurl and SFTP. If possible how? If not why and what are the best alternatives that need minimum changes to existing c++ client developed with libcurl and SFTP.
Edit: I want to try this in Linux.

What platform are you on? Windows or *nix?

Sorry to mention it in the post. It’s linux

What "security reasons"?

First step would be to search the API of libcurl. If it doesn't have such a feature, search their bug tracker for according requests. If that doesn't turn up anything either, file a request yourself and start implementing it.

@MartinPrikryl What security reasons? -> In my system, there is an another service to store certificates and files. That service returns only string via their api. I’m trying to use that string for authentication.

On Linux you have a few simple options:

Use memfd_create to create a bespoke in-memory filehandle.
Use pipe to create a pair of linked file descriptors.

In both scenarios you write the private key to the provided file descriptor and tell curl to read from /proc/self/fd/X or /dev/fd/X.
